# Rank of a matrix related to consistency

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

I have a question about the rank of matrices and its relation to a linear system being consistent. I do not intuitively understand why the rank of the coefficient matrix being equal to the rank of the augmented matrix grants consistency for a linear system of equations. I understand that linear systems of equations that are consistent have this property, but why is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

To solve a linear system, we perform the elimination on it. After a series of routine operations, we obtain those equations that are truly *efficient* to provide the solution; meanwhile the LHS of the rest of them are cancelled to be 0. If the ranks agree, then we will not obtain some equation like $0 = 1$ which is obviously false. Otherwise $0=1$ holds for no solutions of this linear system, hence inconsistent.

In a textbook for a first course of linear algebra, it might be proved that after Gaussian elimination, the linear system could be equivalently convert to something like this [maybe 5 equations in 8 unknowns]:

\begin{alignat*}{9}
&x_1& + & 0 x_2  &+& a_3 x_3 &  + &0x_4&  + &a_5 x_5& + &a_6x_6& + &0x_7&  + &0x_8& = &y_a&\\
&      &  &  1x_2  & +& b_3 x_3 & + &0x_4 & +&  b_5x_5& + &b_6x_6& + &0x_7& + &0x_8& = &y_b&\\
&      &    &             &  &  &
&1x_4& +& c_5 x_5&  + &c_6 x_6& + &0x_7& + &0x_8& = &y_c&\\
&        &   &   &  && && && && &1x_7& + &0x_8& = &y_d&\\
&& && && && && && && &1x_8& =&y_e&
\end{alignat*}
Clearly this is consistent no matter which values $a_j, b_j$ etc. take. This is correspondent to the so called "row-reduced echelon form".

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. However, answering this question with the definition of rank in mind - the number of linearly independent row vectors - how can you approach your answer? In other words, why does having equal number of linearly independent row vectors in the two situations lead to consistency?

Answer (score 0):

Rank is the maximal number of linearly independent columns. If the rank of the augmented matrix $[A|b]$ is equal to the rank of the coefficient matrix $A$, this means that the right-hand side column $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ (otherwise the rank of the augmented matrix is higher). And that is exactly the existence of a solution: $Ax$ is a linear combination of columns of $A$ with coefficients given by the coordinates of $x$, so a solution of $Ax=b$ exists if an only if $b$ is a linear combination of columns of $A$.